# Creating dynamic cards from an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dynamic, material-ui, react-props

I am trying to create 3 using the same component, titled "month 1" "month 2" and "month 3" the cards contain a table and i need to add a header to each card from an array.

I have tried to use properties to iterate over the array, and I have gotten the 3 tables to populate within 3 cards, but I cannot get the titles to populate

```
App.JS

function App() {
  const months = ['month 1', 'month 2', 'month 3'];
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <NavBar/>
      <>
        {months.map(month => <SimpleCard> {month}</SimpleCard>)}
      </>
      <Container>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className='submitButton' id='submitButton'>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Container>
    </div>

  );
}


card.JS

export default function SimpleCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h5" component="h2">
          {/*This is where the month should be displayed*/}

        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
          <Table/>
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

I need the months to be displayed inside of the card, above the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just accept the props on the child, and render the children passed to the component

```
export default function SimpleCard(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h5" component="h2">
          {props.children}
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
          <Table/>
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

For your use case though, I think it would be better to pass the title as an expicit title prop

```
{months.map(month => <SimpleCard title={month} />)}
```

and to render it

```
{props.title}
```